# Timezone and SimpleDateFormat strange behavior

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, simpledateformat

if I execute this code:

```
String data = "08/02/1941";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(data);
```

I have in output the date: `Sat Feb 08 01:00:00 CEST 1941`

instead if I execute this code:

```
String data = "08/02/1971";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = dateFormat.parse(data);
```

the date is: `Sat Feb 08 01:00:00 CET 1971`.

Why do I have this difference (CET and CEST)?

My timezone is Europe/Berlin (UTC+1) and I'm using `Java 1.7.0_67-b01`

Comment: You have `1941` being reported in both outputs.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## War Time — Shifting Time Zones

Daylight Saving Time was [observed all year long in 1941](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/germany/berlin?year=1941) in Berlin. Known by some as "Hitler Time" according to this [history of DST in Europe.](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/europe/daylight-saving-history.html)

The times zones of Europe [shifted around dramatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe#Germany) during and after the war. For example, [this post](http://www.rafcommands.com/forum/showthread.php?1986-WW2-time-differences) (supposedly from Royal Observatory of Greenwich) describes some of these shifts including "Double" DST. These shifts are interesting cases of time zones playing a significant role in history. [At least one academic](http://www.academia.edu/4675982/Daylight_Saving_Energy_Saving._Time_Politics_as_Crisis_Strategy_in_Germany_France_and_the_U.S) uses the term "chronopolitics" for such phenomenon.

## Date-only

If you want to represent a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone, use the `LocalDate` classe.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1941 , Month.FEBRUARY , 8 ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 1941-02-08

The time zone issues discussed above drop away.

Comment: Not holding, just a summary heading like I use on many of my answers. Relevant as this is an interesting case where a time zone played a role in history. Try reading the history as I am at this moment.

Comment: +1 for historical correctness where political correctness fails.

Comment: After reading more history, turns out that the year-round DST of 1941 was not a one-off event by Hitler. Rather, all kinds of crazy time zone changes were a part of the war and even the post-war period. So, I changed the heading to emphasize the bigger picture. And make a pun of "war time".

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you also for historial explanation.